# Cant donwload Video with pytube(HTTP Error 403:Forbidden)

Tags: python, error-handling, youtube, pytube

I am trying to download a YouTube video with the module pytube, but when i use the method to download a video, it tells me:

*urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden*

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0")

stream = yt.streams.first()

stream.download()
```

How can i work around this restriction?

Comment: "Forbidden" means what it says. YouTube has decided you're not allowed to do that. (Because maybe too many requests, but could be lots of reasons. 

There may be a cooldown that will let you try later. No workaround.

Comment: It is a "bug" in pytube (due to changes in youtube). See https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/399 The workarounds do not work for me. I would wait for the next pytube version.

Comment: disregard last, checkout the fix: https://github.com/choten/pytube

Comment: @Coding Tried today, but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As of August 4 2021, there has been a fix in ver 11.
Simply download uninstall with pip uninstall pytube and then reinstall with pip install pytube and it should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same problem. I found unfinished downloaded file in the project folder. After deleting the unfinished downloaded file and running stream.download() again, it worked. So maybe worth checking.

Or like BoarGules mentioned in the comment, it could be a cooldown and try again later (But this happened the first time I am using pytube, never did any downloads before).

pytube version 12.0.0